# How can I use cloud SQL (postgres) server as SSH host to connect from Datastream?

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, ssh-tunnel, google-datastream

I am trying to connect to my Cloud SQL PostgreSQL database from Datastream (to get data to BigQuery). I am using public IP, and since it's set up to require trusted client certificates, my understanding is that I need to use Forward-SSH tunnel as connectivity method from Datastream (please correct me if I'm wrong on this).

According to [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/network-connectivity-options?_ga=2.79772567.-1219948612.1675095489&_gac=1.36507668.1697376040.EAIaIQobChMI0r76u5L4gQMVhrPVCh0GbAoVEAAYASAAEgKve_D_BwE#sshtunnel), it should be possible to use the database server to terminate the SSH tunnel. It does not specify in detail how to do it, only to "*allow network traffic to reach the tunnel server or database host via SSH, which is generally on TCP port 22*".

I am not able to connect, and getting the error
"*We can't connect to the data source. Verify that the Forward SSH tunnel configuration is configured correctly in the connection profile and that the port is open on the SSH tunnel server.*"

I created a connectivity test on the database confirming that port 22 is not reachable.

How can I get this to work? Is there any setting up that needs to be done on the database side? How do I allow traffic on port 22? Or should I use a different port?

Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Have you created an SSH tunnel and did it work? Do you know what an ssh tunnel is and how you use one? if not just google that term and get familiar with it first. The point is to route traffic to your database server (probably on port 5432) without making the database server publicly accessible unless you have authorization to connect to the ssh server.

Comment: I don't have very much insight to it, but this is also what made me doubt the need for an SSH tunnel in the first place. I didn't think it was necessary as long as my database has a public IP, but still I can not figure out another way to make it work with a client certificate.

Comment: "it's set up to require trusted client certificates"  What is "it" in this sentence?  client certs in PostgreSQL is a SSL thing, not an SSH thing.  You could set up PostgreSQL to use SSL with client certs but also require SSH tunneling, but that would be a weird way to set things up.

Comment: It's the cloud SQL instance that is set up to require a certificate. Agree that it is a bit weird. Which is also why I think it's strange that Datastream doesn't seem to be able to use client certificates and public IP to connect? At least I couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud SQL Postgres recently (over the past couple of weeks) has updated its "Require SSL" setting to be more configurable. In the past specifying "Allow only SSL connections" forced successful connections to use mTLS and client certificates. Now the settings are more flexible and granular.

[image]

I would recommend for most cases users select `Allow only SSL connections` which will force successful connections to encrypt traffic and use SSL (but not force mTLS + client certs). This setting will allow for users to use the [IP Allowlist Connectivity Option](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/network-connectivity-options) for Datastream and be able to follow along with the [Datastream Getting Started Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/quickstart-replication-to-bigquery) while still forcing an encrypted connection.

For users that do want the additional overhead of managing client certs and requiring mTLS they can add this by selecting `Require trusted client certificates` in the manage SSL setting of their Cloud SQL instance.

In this case than yes like you mentioned you would be required to use the [SSH Tunnel Datastream Connectivity Option](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/network-connectivity-options#sshtunnel).

My understanding is that since your source database is a Cloud SQL Postgres instance with a Public IP than you have to configure a tunnel server (GCE VM) and are not able to use the database server directly. The reason for this being that Cloud SQL is a managed service and the database server is on a protected "Cloud SQL" network. You will want to instead create a compute engine VM to act as your tunnel/ssh server where you can control the TCP firewall and port-forwarding rules at a more granular level. The use of the database server as the host to terminate the tunnel would be more so for the use-case where your source database was a self-hosted Postgres database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please also clarify why the datastream can't connect to a PostgreSQL instance that expects Certificate Authentication? At least I couldn't find how to do it here: https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/create-connection-profiles#cp4postgresdb (I can also make this an SO question :) )